# Weird out put from a MATLAB function i created

Tags: matlab, function

I am creating a function in MATLAB to preform the bilinear transform going from z domain to s domain.  As far as i know MATLAB has a built in that only goes from s to z.  I pass the function 5 variables ranging from -10 to 10 but when it displays my equation they have values in the order of 10^16.  The code and the output are as follows below:

function:

```
function [ F ] = Bilinear1( A1, B0, B1, C0, C1 )
%%Convert from z-transform to Laplace

syms s;
T=1/60;
disp(' A1 B0 B1 C0 C1')
disp(A1)
disp(B0)
disp(B1)
disp(C0)
disp(C1)

%P = (B1*z + B0)/(z + A1);
%z = ((2+s*T)/(2-s*T));

Vol = ((B1*(2+s*T)/(2-s*T))+B0)/(((2+s*T)/(2-s*T))+A1);
Fre = ((C1*(2+s*T)/(2-s*T))+C0)/(((2+s*T)/(2-s*T))+A1);

F = Vol + Fre

end
```

Output:

```
A1 B0 B1 C0 C1

0.9993

0.3816

-0.3107

1.4454

-2.0896


F =

- (((5596314615617219*s)/1080863910568919040 + 5596314615617219/9007199254740992)/(s/60      - 2) + 1718521318749205/4503599627370496)/((s/60 + 2)/(s/60 - 2) - 9000946589363061/9007199254740992) - (((4705274087128031*s)/135107988821114880 + 4705274087128031/1125899906842624)/(s/60 - 2) + 6509326018898365/4503599627370496)/((s/60 + 2)/(s/60 - 2) - 9000946589363061/9007199254740992)
```

Any help understanding what is causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually tried looking at what those weird fractions are?
 For instance, when evaluating the last term in your F, I get:
9000946589363061/9007199254740992 = 0.9993 = A1, which is what it should be! I am not sure why Matlab replaces 0.993 by this expression, but I am guessing that it should not change your results in any way.
You could try using the [simplify](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) and [simplifyFraction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplifyfraction.html) functions, as well as the [pretty prints](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html) in order to check that all those expressions are correct!

FYI, when copying and pasting your code in my Matlab (R2012b), I get the following output for F:

```
F = - (((653*s)/18750 + 2612/625)/(s/60 - 2) + 7227/5000)/((s/60 + 2)/(s/60 - 2) - 9993/10000) - (((3107*s)/600000 + 3107/5000)/(s/60 - 2) + 477/1250)/((s/60 + 2)/(s/60 - 2) - 9993/10000)
```

which obviously does not use the same integers to write the same fractions... I am guessing that Matlab converts decimal numbers to fractions in order to use them in a syms expression. I don't know why the conversion is different for you than for me! Could you try the [numden](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numden.html) function on A1?

```
[n, d] = numden(syms(0.993))
```

returns n = 993 and d = 1000 for me, and A1 was replaced by 993/1000 in my output. Maybe the result of this would be n = 9000946589363061 and d = 9007199254740992 for you?

Comment: Thanks, the ridiculous size of the numbers kept me from seeing that. the version I'm using is R2013a so im guessing that might have something to do with the different representation of the numbers.  I would try numden right now, but im getting the License Manager Error -15.  Im guessing its just not my day lol.